# "generateds" tag is too similar to "generated" - it is not allowed

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[generateDS](https://pypi.org/project/generateDS/) is a Python module to convert an [XML schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) into a Python module to parse XML instance documents.

When trying to add new tag to an existing question, Stack Overflow had an error saying [generateds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generateds) tag is too similar to [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generated) tag.

Some related questions:

- [Python, generateDS, ref attributes from schema doesn't get properly generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158458/python-generateds-ref-attributes-from-schema-doesnt-get-properly-generated)
- [Py GenerateDS - Export changes float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340988/py-generateds-export-changes-float-to-int)
- [generateDS stops processing child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005920/generateds-stops-processing-child-elements)
- [Validate Python classes created from generateDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258398/validate-python-classes-created-from-generateds)
- [What version of generateDS is to be used for Python 3.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409544/what-version-of-generateds-to-be-use-for-python-3-0-0)
- etc.

Comment: That tag would be guaranteed to be misused anyway (probably why the system doesn't allow it) so something more unambiguous would be a lot better.

Comment: Maybe add a hyphen? generate-ds? Or python-generateds?

Comment: Thanks [python-generateds] probably would be less likely to be misspelled or misused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system doesn't allow you to create a new tag that is the same as an existing tag but with an "s" appended to the end. The idea is that we don't allow both plural and singular versions of the same tag.

Now, this is a bit of a special case, since you're not trying to create a plural form of the [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generated) tag, but rather a new tag for something called "generateDS". Unfortunately, the system doesn't know that, and, as was pointed out in the comments, even we forced the system to allow such a tag to be created, it would be prime for ambiguity and misuse.

Therefore, also as was suggested in the comments, a tag name like [python-generateds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-generateds) is probably more appropriate. Such a tag has now been created and applied to the questions, so I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Also, thanks for creating an *excellent* tag wiki and excerpt; I have gone ahead and approved those.

---

On a somewhat unrelated note… that [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generated) tag is *not* a good tag and should probably go bye-bye.

Comment: The [generated] tag only has a handful of questions and agree it's not very useful. How do you retire a tag?